# Is Reack hook affecting the app performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-hooks

Currently, we need to import all hooks at the top of the component even if we need the hook at a later point. Since the hooks are imported at the top level, any change in the hook rerenders the parent component itself. Is there any better way to avoid this?.

For eg., The parent component will get initialized and will wait for `isFetching` to settle. Ideally in this case we should see three renders - Initial render, second render when `isFetching` is true and third render when `isFetching` is false. But I am seeing multiple rerenders after the initial render because of the custom hook changes (In the profiler the reason for re-render). Using `memo` in the parent component doesn't help.

```
<Parent>
  customHook1();
  customHook2();
  ...
  customHookn();
  return (
    isFetching ? Loader : <child hook components .../>
  )
</Parent>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you should do that? 
Also, what about using `useMemo`? you can use it in order to check dependencies for each specific component

Comment: @HasanAbbasi Consider this use case, one of the customHook need to re-render because of the state changes. The parent component is not yet ready to consume i.e., we are still showing the loader. Still the parent component re-renders.

Comment: I don't understand your `customHook1()` in the render return, this isn't where hooks are used. Perhaps you're just over-simplifying your "pseudocode" though. Are you only asking this question because you believe your component should only rerender under certain conditions and have *some* perceived performance issue, or have you *actually* audited the performance of your code and have an actual performance issue? ***Don't prematurely optimize.*** React is optimized and runs well out-of-the-box. Do you have a more accurate and comprehensive component code example for us to examine?